# Creating view to calculate a previous message

Tags: oracle, sql-view

I'm trying to build a view which shows me the previous message for each message.

I simplyfied the SQL to only show the correspending part, you can see it in this [SQL-fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/10d4cb/1), but to be secure from broken links here's the schema

table `messages`:

```
message_nr | user | value
```

table `messageStatus`:

```
id | message_nr | status | status_recieved_at
```

What I tried to achieve is a view where for an defined `message_nr` the previous message will be calculated. The previous message is definied by the same `user` and the maximum `status_recieved_at` lower than the `status_recieved_at` of the message to be calculated for. Only messages with the "finished" status (in this example `3`) could be a and have previous message.

So the expected result for the view would be

```
+---------+-----------------+
| message | previousMessage |
+---------+-----------------+
|       1 | NULL            |
|       2 | 1               |
|       3 | NULL            |
|       5 | 3               |
|       6 | 2               |
|       7 | NULL            |
+---------+-----------------+
```

Message 4 is not in the table as it has never reached the final status.

To reach this I wrote the following select statement

```
create view whatsThePreviousMessage as (

    select m.message_nr as message, p.message_nr as previousMessage
    from messages m
    join messageStatus msm on (msm.message_nr = m.message_nr and msm.status = 3)
    left join messages p on (p.user = m.user)
    join messageStatus msp on (msp.message_nr = p.message_nr and msp.status = 3)

    where msp.status_recieved_at < msm.status_recieved_at
    order by msp.status_recieved_at desc
)
```

As you can expect this gives me all messages with a lower `status_recieved_at` and not only the row with the maxium one. The output of the SQLfiddle is also much different than I expected.

I though I could reduce the numbers of by using `rownum <= 1` but I don't know how to recuce it for each message as I don't want to reduce the total result to only one row.

**Edit**: I also tried this statement for the SELECT-part:

```
    select m.message_nr as message, p.message_nr as previousMessage, msm.status_recieved_at as mDate, msp.status_recieved_at as pDate
    from messages m
    join messageStatus msm on (msm.message_nr = m.message_nr and msm.status = 3)

    left join messages p on (p.user = m.user)
    join messageStatus msp on (msp.message_nr = p.message_nr and msp.status = 3)
    where msp.status_recieved_at = ( select max(ms3.status_recieved_at)  from messageStatus ms3 join messages m3 on (m3.message_nr = ms3.message_nr and ms3.status = 3 and m.user = m3.user) where ms3.status_recieved_at < msm.status_recieved_at)
    or msp.status_recieved_at is null
```

But this doesn't include the messages which doesn't have a previous message into the result. Furthermore the SQLfiddle can't execute it while my H2 database can. **Note** I need a working solution for **Oracle**. H2 is just for local testing and the SQLfiddle for posting on Stackoverflow!

Comment: Your question is tagged as Oracle, your SQLFiddle uses MySQL while your reference to an H2 database makes me think you might be using an H2 DBMS. Please can you clarify which RDBMS you are actually using?

Comment: @MarkBannister I need a working solution for Oracle. H2 is just for local testing and the SQLfiddle for posting on Stackoverflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select
    messages.message_nr message,
    lag(messages.message_nr) over (partition by messages."USER" order by messagestatus.status_recieved_at) previousmessage
from
    messages
    join messagestatus on messages.message_nr = messagestatus.message_nr and messagestatus.status = 3
order by
    messages.message_nr;
```

Comment: Wow! After looking up what the `LAG` function does this seems pretty nice. I'll test it tomorrow and give you response!